# Can someone explain what request message would be sent when a user types the URL http://www.it.brighton.ac.uk/index.html into their browser

Tags: javascript, html, url, request, response

I am teaching myself html, javascript etc. and I am trying to attend the University of Brighton and so I have managed to get some tutorial questions to help me learn more.

Could someone please explain, what request message would be sent when a user types the URL http://www.it.brighton.ac.uk/index.html into their browser and what the response message back from the server would be?

I really do not understand what this would be and would appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Download or open Chrome browser, open developer tools, click on network tab, go to the site and you can see details of the request and response in the network tab

Comment: any modern browser has developer tools

Answer (score 1):

Here is a screenshot of Firefox's "Web Developer Network Inspector".

[image: Network Tab > Headers]

You can see the message sent by your browser under the `Request Headers` dropdown, and it does so by using the GET request method.

To look at more network requests on your own, you can reach it with the following steps:

**Chrome**
More Tools > Developer Tools > Network tab (at the top)

**Firefox**
Tools > Web Developer > Network